# Threads that read from text files concurently and place data in arrays

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, file-io, global-variables

The goal of this code is to run four threads, which will open four text files, read the words from them and then place them into a string array,

Main problems i know of:

1- I am not putting the concurrent function in the void run function, I want to be able to pass parameters into that function

2- I am not sure if I am modifying the global arrays of strings or not either

First is the main method:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
         //declare the threads
         Thread thread1 =  new Thread(ReadFile("list1.txt", Global.array1,"thread1"));
         Thread thread2 =  new Thread(ReadFile("list2.txt", Global.array2,"thread2"));
         Thread thread3 =  new Thread(ReadFile("list3.txt", Global.array3,"thread1"));
         Thread thread4 =  new Thread(ReadFile("list4.txt", Global.array4,"thread2"));

         /*error message from netbeans: cannot find symbol
            symbol:   method ReadFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String[])

            it says it for every delcaration of the thread*/


         thread1.start();  //putting the threads to work
         thread2.start();
         thread3.start();
         thread4.start();

         thread1.join();   //telling the threads to finish their work
         thread2.join();
         thread3.join();
         thread4.join();


         // merging the arrays into one
         List list = new ArrayList(Arrays.asList(Global.array1));
         list.addAll(Arrays.asList(Global.array2));
         list.addAll(Arrays.asList(Global.array3));
         list.addAll(Arrays.asList(Global.array4));
         Object[] theArray = list.toArray();

           -------------------------etc----------------------------
```

This is the "thread class" if my vocab is right

```
public class ReadFile implements Runnable
{
    public void run(){
            //I should get stuff here, that's my problem!!!!
    }


    private String path;
    Thread runner;

    public ReadFile(String filePath, String[] toArray, String threadName) throws IOException
    {
        String path = filePath;
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(path);
        BufferedReader textReader = new BufferedReader(fr);

        int numOfLines = readLines();  
        toArray = new String[numOfLines];

        int i;
        for (i=0; i<numOfLines; i++)
        {
            toArray[i]= textReader.readLine();    //place next line into string array
        }

        textReader.close();
    }


   int readLines() throws IOException
    {
        FileReader fr = new FileReader(filePath);
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String aLine;
        int noOfLines = 0;

        while((aLine = bf.readLine()) != null)
        {
            noOfLines++;
        }
        bf.close();
        return noOfLines;
    }

    }
```

---

Finally i did a class for the global variable, and i don't know if it's a good idea

```
public class Global 
{
    public static String[] array1;
    public static String[] array2;
    public static String[] array3;
    public static String[] array4;
}
```

please let me know what you guys think, any help or explanations or tips would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What, specifically, is your problem and question?

Comment: the problem is that the thread function seems wrong in terms of the syntax so the main isn't working either

Comment: Isn't working how? You need to be more specific and provide more info for us to be able to help you.

Comment: will do. just a sec please i'll do my best

Comment: Agree with @Keppil -- the better the question, usually the better the answer. This will mean significant effort on your part.

Comment: I recommend you use IOUtils.readFully() to get the content of the file in one shot. Also, make use of the Runnable interface and create the Threads from that. But honestly, why would you even attempt such a thing instead of a sequential read?!?

Comment: You are mistakenly reading the file in the constructor of the thread rather than in the `run()` method.

Comment: i just added the message why it says it whon't compile, and added comments, hope this helps

Comment: @Duncan Jones Yes i think the problem is around that issue, would you mind elaborating a little on your comment please

Comment: @Duncan Jones i don't know why your editing was rejected, although it's a very good job you did

Comment: @Ryan Luck of the draw. I've added an answer that expands on my comment.

Comment: I am having a look at the comments and trying to learn, improve and then edit to reflect where I currently reached, thanks I'm reading around and pondering all comments and answers until I get it :)

Comment: @Ryan you should **REALLY** use [executors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html).

Comment: @Ryan your major issue is that there is no method `ReadFile`, but there is a `ReadFile` class and it has a constructor. You need to be doing your work in the `run` method if you want the work to be concurrent. How does `readLines` work? You're never modifiying the `global` arrays, since you reinitialize the `toArray` parameter in your constructor.

Comment: @veer those were extremely helpful insights, i'll try to figure out the issues at hand immediately and tell you how it goes

Comment: @Ryan I see you're still having trouble. Anything in particular still an issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we first fix your file reading thread, so that the main work occurs in the `run()` method:

```
public class FileReader extends Thread {

  private final File file;
  private String[] lines;

  public FileReader(File file) {
    this.file = file;
  }

  @Override
  public void run() {
    // Read file here (populate `lines`)..
  }

  public String[] getLines() {
    return lines;
  }
}
```

Then we can utilise this in the `main` method, as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  List<FileReader> threads = new ArrayList<FileReader>();

  threads.add(new FileReader(new File("foo1")));
  threads.add(new FileReader(new File("foo2")));
  threads.add(new FileReader(new File("foo3")));
  threads.add(new FileReader(new File("foo4")));

  for (FileReader t : threads) {
    t.start();
  }

  List<String> allLines = new ArrayList<String>();

  for (FileReader t : threads) {
    t.join();
    allLines.addAll(Arrays.asList(t.getLines()));
  }    

  // File lines now in allLines
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your constructor signature for `ReadFile`:

```
public ReadFile(String filePath, String[] toArray, String threadName)
```

does not match with the calls in `main` (you are only providing `String`, `String[]`). I think you meant:

```
Thread thread1 =  new Thread(new ReadFile("list1.txt", Global.array1, "thread1"));
Thread thread2 =  new Thread(new ReadFile("list2.txt", Global.array2, "thread2"));
Thread thread3 =  new Thread(new ReadFile("list3.txt", Global.array3, "thread1"));
Thread thread4 =  new Thread(new ReadFile("list4.txt", Global.array4, "thread2"));
```

You were probably confused by the fact that `ReadFile`'s constructor takes the `threadName` as the third parameter, but the `Thread` class itself also has a similar parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Three mistakes:

1. `ReadFile` is a class implementing `Runnable`, so you should pass an instance to the `Thread` constructor:

   Thread thread1 = new Thread(new ReadFile("list1.txt", Global.array1),"thread1");
2. Why create a `Thread` inside `ReadFile`? Remove that, no additional runner needed!
3. The `ReadFile` constructor has an additional parameter `threadName` which has to be removed.

Comment: 1. That's what he's doing. 2. I agree with this.

Comment: 1. no, he missed the keyword new before ReadFile!